# PHP- Unable to Access Data from DB in dropdown menu

Tags: php

I am trying to create a drop down menu that will display Project Names off all Projects present in  the table Project in the database Testing... The drop down is created but it is not accessing the database and retrieving the required data...
The code is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Dynamic Drop Down List</title>
</head>

    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>">
        Project List :
        <select Project Name='NEW'>
        <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
        <?
            $serverName = "Swagatha-PC"; 
            $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Testing");
            $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

            if( $conn ) 
            {
            echo "Connection established.<br />";
            }
            else
            {
            echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
            }
            if (isset ($select)&&$select!="")
            {
            $select=$_POST ['NEW'];
        }
        ?>
        <?
            $query=mysql_query("select ProjectName from dbo.Project");
            $menu=" ";
            while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query))
            {
               $menu ="<option>" . $row["ProjectName"] . "</option>";
            }


            ?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="Next" value="Select" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[Dropdown Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrdUJ.jpg)

What Do i do to fix this??

Comment: `mysql_query` and `sqlsrv_fetch_array`? hmm.. Not even a [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php). But for real, you're probably looking for [sqlsrv_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php)

Comment: echo is missing in the while loop

Answer (score 1):

The solution is

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query))
{
   echo "<option>" . $row["ProjectName"] . "</option>";
}
```

See? You output data with `echo` instead assinging data to variable.

And as @FirstOne noticed using `mysql_query` with `sqlsrv_connect` is an error too. I hope it's just your typo:

```
$query=sqlsrv_query($conn, "select ProjectName from dbo.Project");
```

As another sidenote

```
if (isset ($select)&&$select!="")
{
    $select=$_POST ['NEW'];
}
```

this `if` will always be false, because you **first** check `$select` and then **define** it. It definitely should be:

```
if (isset($_POST['NEW']) && $_POST['NEW'] != "")
{
    $select = $_POST['NEW'];
}
```

Comment: Besides from connecting with `sqlsrv_connect` and running `mysql_query` xD

Comment: Yeah, mentioned it, I suppose now we can close this as dupe(

Comment: Nope its still not working..Have made both the changes

Comment: I feel like commenting here because this will become more complete, instead of a bunch of answers with each a little info. Sorry if it's trouble for ya ^^. 1: the op doesn't have anything setting `$select` before `if (isset ($select)&&$select!="")`. 2: `<select Project Name='NEW'>` what's `Project` supposed to mean? 3: `$select=$_POST ['NEW'];` seems like a self fulfilling prophecy - though it will never be fulfilled xD since to select something, you'll need to have selected something (new is the name of the select itself).

Comment: @FirstOne It doesn't seem to be working still..Not gttng wer i hv gone wrong

Answer (score 0):

Here is you fixed code. You can try it

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Dynamic Drop Down List</title>
</head>

    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>">
        Project List :
        <select Project Name='NEW'>
        <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
        <?php
            $serverName = "Swagatha-PC"; 
            $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Testing");
            $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

            if( $conn ) 
            {
            echo "Connection established.<br />";
            }
            else
            {
            echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
            }
            if (isset ($select)&&$select!="")
            {
            $select=$_POST ['NEW'];
        }


            $query=sqlsrv_query("select ProjectName from dbo.Project");
            $menu=" ";
            while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query))
            {
               echo "<option>" . $row["ProjectName"] . "</option>";
            }


            ?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="Next" value="Select" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove `=` after `echo`

Comment: Thanks for suggested me @u_mulder